# Haskell: AST reduction causing type issues

Tags: haskell

I have the following code for an extensible AST. My goal was to allow more expression types to be added later with the `Expr` class and not have all of the types in a single data block.

```
data Constant o = Constant o deriving (Show)
data Add l r o = Add (l o) (r o) deriving (Show)

class Expr e where
  simplify :: (Expr a, Num o) => (e o) -> (a o)

instance Expr Constant where
  simplify (Constant a) = Constant a

instance (Expr l, Expr r) => Expr (Add l r) where
  simplify (Add l r) = case (simplify l, simplify r) of
    (Conatant a, Constant b) -> Constant $ a + b
    (sl@_, sr@_) -> Add sl sr
```

I'm running into these errors:

```
math.hs:10:27: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Constant’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          simplify :: forall (a :: * -> *) o.
                      (Expr a, Num o) =>
                      Constant o -> a o
        at math.hs:10:3-10
      Expected type: a o
        Actual type: Constant o
    • In the expression: Constant a
      In an equation for ‘simplify’: simplify (Constant a) = Constant a
      In the instance declaration for ‘Expr Constant’
    • Relevant bindings include
        simplify :: Constant o -> a o (bound at math.hs:10:3)

math.hs:15:21: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Add l0 r0’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          simplify :: forall (a :: * -> *) o.
                      (Expr a, Num o) =>
                      Add l r o -> a o
        at math.hs:13:3-10
      Expected type: a o
        Actual type: Add l0 r0 o
    • In the expression: Add sl sr
      In a case alternative: (sl@_, sr@_) -> Add sl sr
      In the expression:
        case (simplify l, simplify r) of { (sl@_, sr@_) -> Add sl sr }
    • Relevant bindings include
        sr :: r0 o (bound at math.hs:15:12)
        sl :: l0 o (bound at math.hs:15:6)
        simplify :: Add l r o -> a o (bound at math.hs:13:3)
```

I can't understand why this doesn't work. Then again, I am fairly new to Haskell from spending almost a decade in OOP land. I'm hoping someone can give me insight on this.

I am trying to do this without any GHC extensions, since I want to understand the vanilla language before I start adding more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ... where
  simplify :: (Expr a, ...) => ... -> (a o)
```

This declaration means than you need to be able to construct `a o` for any type which is in class Expr, selected by usage of `simplify`. You cannot specify in instances concrete type.

**Edit**: you could introduce into Expr a construction:

```
class Expr e where
    ...
    constant :: a -> e a
    add :: e a -> e a -> e a
    ...
```

And use those. Though expressions like (add _ _ :: Constant Int) would not make sense.

**What you could do** is to **specify class with dependency**:

```
class Simplify e1 e2 | e1 -> e2 where ...
```

Or **with type family**:

```
class Simplify e where
    data Simplified e :: *
    ....
```

They would need corresponding extensions, but you should not fear it. That's what modern Haskell is.

Comment: That is very concise. Thank you. I guess I will take a leap into using the extensions. It is funny how many of these extensions have been around since Haskell 98 and they're not just standard in the language yet.